# Not floating on same line, how to fix css

Tags: html, css

```
<div>
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chxSEN" runat="server" Text="Question" onchange="hideDiv('DIV')"/>
  <div id="DIV" style="display:none">
    <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text="Question 2" CssClass="lbl2"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="lbl3" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox"></asp:TextBox>
  </div>
</div>
```

If i add css class to the div id DIV to float it right, it should appear on the same line as the checkbox right?

Its appearing under the checkbox question..

I checked for 
 (looks like it is having a break) but none in the code.

Comment: please share the HTML after executing the ASP.NET code, Is possible try showing use the ASPX code and CSS written by you in detail..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uPc6N/3/)**. For Demo purpose I used HTML form controls.

**CSS:**

```
#DIV {
    display:inline-block;
}
#chxSEN {
    display:none;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" ID="chxSEN" runat="server" Text="Question" />
<div id="DIV">
    <label>Test</label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#DIV").hide();
    $("#chxSEN").show();

    $('#chxSEN').click(function () {
        $("#DIV").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, and i kinda like the slideToggle ;)!

Answer (score 0):

Changed your asp controls with html ones for fiddle example.

**html**

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" ID="chxSEN" runat="server" Text="Question" />
    <div id="DIV" style="display:none">
        <label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text="Question 2" CssClass="lbl2">test</label>
        <input type="textbox" ID="lbl3" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
    div > input, #lbl{
      float:left;
    }
```

Also i created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cd8vd/7/) with entire solution.